# Как сделать срабатывание inline кнопки только для одного пользователя канала? Telebot Python

Tags: python, telebot

есть бот, через которого создаются заказы и пересылаются в канал, где люди могут "взять" заказ в работу. [image: Пример заказа]

После того, как пользователь нажимает на кнопку, бот изменяет это сообщение и присылает ему данные о заказе. Код:

```
bot.edit_message_text('Заказ принял '+ c.from_user.first_name, channel, c.message.id)
        for i in admin:
            bot.forward_message(i, channel, c.message.id)
            bot.send_message(i, '*Заказ принял:* '+ c.from_user.first_name + ' \n *Его username:* @'+str(c.from_user.username) +' \n *Его ID:* '+ str(c.from_user.id), parse_mode='Markdown')
        bot.forward_message(c.from_user.id, channel, c.message.id)
        bot.send_message(c.from_user.id, 'Вы приняли заказ! Позвоните по номеру и уточните все подробности')
```

В чем заключается проблема. Если пользователь нажмет на кнопку много раз, то кнопка несколько раз сработает. Если несколько пользователей нажмут на кнопку, то она для них всех сработает. Нужно сделать, чтобы кнопка только для одного пользователя срабатывала.
Не могу понять как решить эту проблему. В интернете ничего не нашел, надеюсь, что тут кто-то поможет.
Заранее спасибо!

Пример, как просили:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

channel = 'channel id'

accept_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
accept_btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Принять', callback_data='accept')
accept_markup.add(accept_btn)


create_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
create_btn = types.KeyboardButton('Создать заказ')
create_markup.add(create_btn)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'С возвращением!', reply_markup=create_markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def create(message):
    bot.send_message(channel, 'Новый заказ', reply_markup=accept_markup)
    
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def order(c):
    if c.data == 'accept':
        bot.edit_message_text('Заказ взял '+ c.from_user.first_name, channel, c.message.id)
        bot.send_message(c.from_user.id, 'Вы приняли заказ')
```

Товарищи работают при помощи аналогичного бота и там если нажать одновременно двум пользователям на кнопку, вылазит сообщение, что коллега пытается взять заказ

Comment: У вас там есть база данных? И добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Проверьте, что заказ с таким `inline_message_id` ещё не взят, перед тем, как обрабатывать нажатие.

Comment: при изменении сообщения убирайте кнопку, а вообще очень странная идея отправлять заказы (индивидуальные?) в канал

Comment: @Violet Если два пользователя одновременно нажмут на кнопку, то на сервер все равно отправится 2 запроса (даже если после первого бот удалит кнопку).

Comment: gil9red, добавил пример. Базу данных использовать будем в будущем, сейчас вручную добавляем записи в CRM.

Comment: Violet, в канале будут состоять только рабочие и кто первый возьмет заказ, тот и работает